# QCombobox для foreign keys

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных, qt

Возникла следующая проблема. Я написал приложение, использующее БД. Изначально для отображения таблиц использовалась QSqlRelationalTableModel и foreign keys можно было изменять и добавлять внутри самого tableView. Выглядело это примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но ввиду некоторых причин было решено сделать редактирование данных БД с помощью форм. Так вот вопрос, как мне передать в QCombobox формы при клике на tableView все используемыe в этой ячейке foreign keys?
Чтобы было примерно вот так (отображаться должны не индексы, а объекты на которые индексы ссылаются):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом случае код выглядел так:

```
    model->setTable(sql_query);
    model->setRelation(1, QSqlRelation("my_schema.aircrafts","id_aircraft","registration_number"));
    model->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("my_schema.airports","id_airport","name_airport"));
    model->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("my_schema.airports","id_airport","name_airport"));
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, "Номер маршрута", Qt::DisplayRole);
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, "Самолет", Qt::DisplayRole);
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, "Наименование маршрута", Qt::DisplayRole);
    model->setHeaderData(3, Qt::Horizontal, "Аэропорт вылета", Qt::DisplayRole);
    model->setHeaderData(4, Qt::Horizontal, "Аэропорт приземления", Qt::DisplayRole);
    model->select();
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(3, new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(4, new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));
    break;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно написать для второго случая.

Comment: Выберите другую колонку модели, помещённой вами в комбобокс, с помощью `QComboBox::setModelColumn`.

Comment: Может немного неправильно выразился. Мне нужно, чтоб в ComboBox передавались значения всех возможных foreign key, которые могут использоваться в ячейке

Comment: А как вы пометили туда цифры?

Comment: `QString query = QString("SELECT * FROM my_schema.route WHERE id_route = '%1'").arg(id);
 QSqlQuery qw;
 qw.exec(query);
 while(qw.next())
  {
   model->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("my_schema.airports","id_airport","name_airport"));
   ui->comboBox_2->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));
   ui->comboBox_2->setModelColumn(3);}`

Comment: По сути вы можете открыть `qsqlrelationaldelegate.h` и посмотреть, что там происходит (Вас интересует `createEditor`).  Вкратце: `combo->setModel(model->relationModel(4)); combo->setModelColumn(1);`. Мы используем модель, содержащую данные, на которые ссылается внешний ключ, как модель комбобокса. `combo` — ваш комбобокс.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо. А не подскажите, если не сложно, как при клике на строку tableView передавать значение в этот comboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `QSqlRelationalTableModel::relationModel` возвращает `QSqlTableModel`, которая представляет таблицу, на которую ссылается внешний ключ (или `nullptr` если для столбца не задана связь). Данную модель и нужно поместить в ваш `QComboBox`.

За создание editor-ов, выставление значений и передачу результатов в модель отвечают делегаты. Данный код можно подсмотреть в соответствующем делегате. Код создания комбобокса с данными внешнего ключа основанный на `QSqlRelationalDelegate::createEditor` (`qsqlrelationaldelegate.h`):

```
int combo_column = 4;
QComboBox* combo = new QComboBox();
QSqlTableModel *childModel = model->relationModel(combo_column);
//Опущена проверка на childModel != nullptr
combo->setModel(childModel);
const QSqlDriver *const driver = childModel->database().driver();
combo->setModelColumn(fieldIndex(childModel, driver, 
                            model->relation(combo_column).displayColumn()));

//....

static int fieldIndex(const QSqlTableModel *const model,
                  const QSqlDriver *const driver,
                  const QString &fieldName)
{
    const QString stripped = driver->isIdentifierEscaped(fieldName, QSqlDriver::FieldName)
             ? driver->stripDelimiters(fieldName, QSqlDriver::FieldName)
        : fieldName;
    return model->fieldIndex(stripped);
}
```

Выставить текущее значение комбобокса можно, например, в слоте по сигналу `QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)`:

```
void onClick(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int comboIndex = combo->findData(index.sibling(index.row(), combo_column).data(), Qt::DisplayRole);
    combo->setCurrentIndex(comboIndex);
}
```

**P.S.** Код изменения данных в модели можно посмотреть в `QSqlRelationalDelegate::setModelData` (`qsqlrelationaldelegate.h`):

```
const QSqlDriver *const driver = childModel->database().driver();

int currentItem = combo->currentIndex();

int childEditIndex = fieldIndex(childModel, driver,
                                model->relation(index.column()).indexColumn());

model->setData(index,
        childModel->data(childModel->index(currentItem, childEditIndex), Qt::EditRole),
        Qt::EditRole);
```

Поведение модели при методе [`setData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#setData) зависит от [стратегии редактирования](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum). В случае кэширования данных можно менять и `Qt::DisplayRole` (см. `qsqlrelationaldelegate.h`)

Comment: Простите, как потом обратно в tableView передать значение индекса foreign key, чтоб редактировать данные в моем внешнем comboBox. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sergey47, отредактировал ответ